# Subset numpy array based on another array

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 numpy arrays:

```
arr_a = array(['1m_nd', '2m_nd', '1m_4wk'],
      dtype='<U15')

arr_b = array([0, 1, 1])
```

I want to select elements from `arr_a` based on `arr_b`. I am doing this:
`arr_a[arr_b]`, but I get this as result:

```
array(['1m_nd', '2m_nd', '2m_nd'],
      dtype='<U15')
```

instead of:

```
array(['2m_nd', '1m_4wk'],
      dtype='<U15')
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: Boolean indexing requires a boolean array.

Answer (score 8):

You need to pass it a boolean array, for example:

```
>>> arr_a[arr_b>0]

array(['2m_nd', '1m_4wk'], 
      dtype='<U15')
```

Answer (score 0):

Given `arr_a` and `arr_b`, Running the following will give the boolean array for each of the elements in `arr_b` whose value is `1 => True` and `0 => False` . Correspondingly the boolean values are checked with the index value in `arr_a`. Here is the line of code you'd need.

```
>>> arr_a[arr_b == 1]
array([u'2m_nd', u'1m_4wk'],
      dtype='<U15')
```